# How can I adjust microphone input levels in HoloLens?

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

In our communications app, some people's voices are too quiet. So we want to be able to change the system level of their microphone input.
I searched through all the Windows Universal App samples and Unity documentation and I couldn't find how to change the volume of the Windows microphone (on Windows or HoloLens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the property to adjust is the [AudioDeviceController.VolumePercent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.devices.audiodevicecontroller.volumepercent?view=winrt-19041) property. The following code implements this:

```
MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
var captureInitSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
{
    StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio
};
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(captureInitSettings);
mediaCapture.AudioDeviceController.VolumePercent = volumeLevel;
```

I confirmed that this code works on Desktop and HoloLens. It changes the system level, so it's automatically persisted, and would affect all apps.